# LARAVEL - Did not update database when submit a form

Tags: laravel

When pressed the submit button nothing happens and did not update database. Please help me.

Controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
         ]);

    //$user = Auth::user();       
    $user = user::where('id',$id)->update($request->except('_token','_method'));

    $user->name = request('name');
    $user->email = request('email');
    $user->password = bcrypt(request('password'));
    $user->firstname = $request->firstname;
    $user->middlename = $request->middlename;
    $user->lastname = $request->lastname;
    $user->birthday = $request->birthday;
    $user->nationality = $request->nationality;
    $user->gender = $request->gender;
    $user->civilstatus = $request->name;
    $user->mobilenum = $request->mobilenum;
    $user->worknum = $request->worknun;
    $user->workadd = $request->workadd;
    $user->homeadd = $request->homeadd;
    $user->email = $request->email;

    $user->save();

    return redirect(route('user.user.show'))->with('message','Announcement Updated Succesfully');;

}
```

edit.blade.php

```
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('user.user.update', $user->id)}}">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
..
..
..
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            <a href="{{ route('user.user.show', $user->id)}}" class="btn btn-warning">Back</a>
```

Routes

```
      Route::get('users/{user}',  ['as' => 'user.user.show', 'uses' => 'UserController@index']);
      Route::get('users/edit/{user}',  ['as' => 'user.user.edit', 'uses' => 'UserController@edit']);
      Route::PATCH('users/update/{users}',  ['as' => 'user.user.update', 'uses' => 'UserController@update']);
```

Please help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Nothing in your Laravel log?

Comment: why you didn't use resource and where is post method ?

Comment: Hi, sorry Im really new with laravel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what i can see i think you're `$request` is not passing the `unique` validation on `email`.

since it's an update function leaving unique fields in a form *(e.g.  email - username)* unchanged will result in a validation error try to bypass it with this:

```
 'email' => ['required','email',Rule::unique('users')->ignore($id)]
```